# Impact of including extensive comments in a JSP page

Tags: jsp, comments

I am curious to know if I include extensive comments in my JSP page, how will it affect compilation time and execution  time?  My JSP pages include a good amount of JavaScript code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSP are basicly Java, it will complie to java bytecode eventually. so it is the same like if there are many comments how it is effect compling in Java. and this has been ask before.check this [Do comments affect compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316173/do-comments-affect-compile-time)